# Helm charts on ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm, amazon-ecr

I am new to helm charts, but had a question that can we push multiple charts on single ECR repo? I have tried uploading the helm chart in one ECR repo, but it always says
"Error: unexpected status: 404 Not Found"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Please show us what you tried to do that lead up to the error

Comment: Found any solution for this error?? I am also facing the same error.